# Each time that I compile, kile creates another Pdf with same file

Tags: compiling, kile

I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24190/building-and-viewing-pdfs-on-kile-opens-multiple-instances-of-the-same-file)
and I know that this not happens, if I use pdf viewers like  evince or okular, but now I use FoxitReader because is lightweight and because I have Fedora 15 spin with LXDE and this edition uses epdfview (that I don't like) for default. Therefore, I uninstalled epdf and I'm happy with Foxit, but when I'm using kile and each time that I compiled a document, kile opens a new pdf.

Then my question is: This happens me for the choice of FoxitReader or is a problem of kile's configuration? How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with your PDF viewer, rather than anything to do with LaTeX or friends. Perhaps this question should be migrated to superuser?

Comment: Foxit won't update a PDF if changes are made to it, so you have to open a new "version" of the PDF to view the changes. The developers have done some work on this feature (http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/showthread.php?17303-Auto-refresh-already-opened-PDF) but so far they have not added it.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are using the Quickbuild command for building your document, and by creating another PDF you actually meant that it opens another viewer.
Go into `Settings->Configure Kile...->Build->Quickbuild` and remove the ViewPDF command. Then you can use the View PDF command manully (just once) (default shortcut Alt+7) and repeat the Quickbuild (Alt+1) as many times as you want.

Update: Foxit doesn't support automatic updates (version 5 even seems to block write access on the file), which would make it unsuitable for usage with LaTeX.

The above setup works nicely with other PDF viewers (Okular, Evince), and it doesn't matter how long time it takes for them to start, since that will only happen once.

Comment: The pdf viewer (FoxitReader) is not actualiced after compile

Comment: This method seems effective and quick. However, it still requires to be at the root document. Is there a way to compile regardless of what is the current file location?