# Visualize PDF document using internal viewer with kile

Tags: viewers, kile

How can I Visualize PDF document using internal viewer with **kile** like in texmaker. I don't like to close the pdf document every time it shows up in a new window. 
Shortly How to Put the pdf document aside my code source on the same window as in Texmaker?
Please can somone tell if there is any possible way to divise the screen in two part in Kile likewise with Texmaker? one part for the Editor and the oder part for the PDF.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24190/building-and-viewing-pdfs-on-kile-opens-multiple-instances-of-the-same-file

Comment: @samcarter I don't think that's the same issue, is it? Why do you keep closing the PDF? I guess you are using the `embedded` viewer, rather than Okular?

Comment: I can't test this because (I think) the embedded viewer on my system is based on Qt5, whereas Kile is still using the deprecated Qt4. At least, it says it can't find the library, although it does exist. But why do you keep closing the PDF? I never do that unless there's a specific problem which confuses Okular. I just keep it open. Side-by-side requires the luxury of a larger screen, so I layer them, but the principle is presumably the same.

Comment: @cfr Based on the sentence "I don't like to close the pdf document every time it shows up in a new window" I thought the underlying problem might be that a new pdf viewer is opened every time and there are multiple answer who suggest to not press "view pdf" to avoid that (this should be independent of the viewer).

Comment: @samcarter It is not entirely independent of the viewer because Okular and the view PDF function can be configured to use the existing window or tab, I think, if the file is already open. But, in this case, the OP is presumably not using a separate viewer at all, but Okular 'part' which is Kile's embedded viewer. I'm not sure though, because I don't think this should open a new window at all, but only probably a tab. That is, probably you're right.

Comment: Thanks for all your great comments but "I think I wrongly explain my problem" whoever use textmaker should get my point. In Textmaker **there is a trick where one can Type a text on the left and see the result on the right after running the programme without neccessarly open the PDF file.** That is what would like to know with Kile, **is there such a trick therein  with Kile?** Since Kile seems to be an advance version of textmaker

Comment: @GuyFsone Have you found a solution in the mean time? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen Unfortunately no I switched back to my lovest Texmaker. it is easy there